# Can we add Listener for custom ArrayAdpater class

Tags: android

I have custom `ArrayAdapter` class for my `listview`.

I am using that custom adapter for more `listviews`.

All the `listview` items have to start the same activity when clicked, how to do that without adding individual itemlistener to each `listview` item?

I have done something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)(context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
        row                     = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        ImageView albumArt      = (ImageView)(row.findViewById(R.id.album_art));
        TextView  albumName     = (TextView)(row.findViewById(R.id.album_name));

        final OnClickListener Listener = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("albumart", album.albumArt);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
            row.setOnClickListener(Listener);
       }
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set an `OnClickListener` on each row, instead set an `OnItemClickListener` on the `ListView`.

In your `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
        // Add code here to get album data from the row...
        intent.putExtra("albumart", album.albumArt);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```